# Create a non-zero instance of any number/primitive value type given a Type in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets say you have a `Type` called `primitiveType` with `primitiveType.IsPrimitive == true`, how can you most succintly (without using a third-party library) create an instance of this with a non-zero value (e.g. value = 1)?

That is, the function could look like:

```
public static object CreateNonZero(Type primitiveType)
{
    if (!primitiveType.IsPrimitive)
    { throw new ArgumentException("type must be primitive"); }

    // TODO
}
```

That is, it should work for all primitive value types e.g. bool, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, IntPtr, UIntPtr, char etc.

Comment: `decimal` is a value type, but not a primitive type.

Comment: Are you sure you care about primitive types? Being primitive is pretty much an implementation detail of the runtime and generally not useful in higher level code. Don't you mean numeric types? Do you want to support `BigInteger` and `Decimal`? What about `bool`, `char` and `IntPtr`?

Comment: sorry yes decimal is not a primitive type, sorry about that. Supporting this would be great too. Yes to bool, char and IntPtr all considered within primitive types, I think. BigInteger would also be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Convert.ChangeType(1, primitiveType)
```

Note if you wanted to have the return type match your actual type rather than be `object`, it's relatively easy to do a generic version:

```
public static T CreateNonZero<T>()
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(T));
}
```

If you want to handle `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`, I don't know of any more elegant way than to check the type explicitly

```
public static object CreateNonZero(Type type)
{
    if(type == typeof(IntPtr))
        return new IntPtr(1);
    if(type == typeof(UIntPtr))
        return new UIntPtr(1);
    return Convert.ChangeType(1, type);
}
```

Comment: Would it be more appropriate in this case to do a regular cast rather than using the `as` operator?  I.e. `return (T) Convert.ChangeType( 1, typeof( T ) )`.  I can't remember off the top of my had what happens when `T` is unconstrained and the `as` operator is used (since `T` could be a value type).

Comment: Doesn't work for `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` which are primitive types.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think there will be any general approach which works with every primitive. Handling `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` would probably require some additional `if` statements.

Comment: @BenAaronson I would love to check your answer as the correct answer, but for this I would prefer if you add perhaps a third example that also handle IntPtr and UIntPtr which I do actually need.

Comment: great thanks! I did not know of the static Convert.ChangeType option so that at least helped me.